# MySQL to Populate Foreach

Tags: php, mysql, email, newsletter

I am working on rebuilding a newsletter system I wrote a while ago. The original system was based around using a flat file system, and I want to convert it over to MySQL. All I have left is to rebuild the end function. My problem is that I need to do is use a loop for every email stored in the database. I figured a each loop is the best way to do this, but how do you use MySQL and foreach together? Here's my current code:

```
    $run = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM newsletter");    

    foreach ($run as $value) { 
        mail($value, $subject, $_POST['message'], $headers);
    }
```

I've tried a lot of different things  and nothing seems to work. I've even tried something like this:

```
        $run = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM newsletter");    
    $email = mysql_fetch_array($run, MYSQL_ASSOC)
    $cols = implode (', ', $email);
    $run2 = mysql_query("SELECT $cols FROM newsletter");    
    while($emaillist = mysql_fetch_array($run2, MYSQL_ASSOC)){ 
        foreach ($emaillist as $value) { 
            mail($value, $subject, $_POST['message'], $headers);
        }                                                                       
    }
```

That was based off of a few other examples i seem. it doesnt give any errors, but it doesnt send the email. I would greatly appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to fetch your results.  You can't use foreach, you'll want to use while.

```
$handle = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM newsletter");    

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $handle ) )
{
    mail( $row['email'], $subject, $_POST['message'], $headers);
}
```

https://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc

Comment: @Johan yes, it's horrible - you should put a comment on the question with a link to what you're talking about so the OP can become educated on the problem. :) ... n/m - just saw your answer.

Comment: I took account of that and added it into my scripting. My site is probably filled with a lot of security risks, but i know know all the functions, nor do I know when to use them most of the time. I've had a lot of people tell me a lot of different things.

Comment: @DwightAaronPotvin if you switch to using PDO with bound parameters you'll be injection safe.

Answer (score 1):

This pseudo code

```
$run = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM newsletter");    

foreach ($run as $value) { 
    mail($value, $subject, $_POST['message'], $headers);
}
```

Can be correctly rewritten as:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT body, emailaddress, subject  FROM emails");    
if (!$result) { die('error in mysql_query: '.mysql_error())}
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) {
  $body = $row['body'];
  $address = $row['address'];
  $subject = $row['subject'];
  //do stuff with that data.
  //never use $_POST data directly, always feed it though `htmlentities` 
  //before outputting it (screen or email) 
  //or through mysql_real_escape_string() before inputting it in a DB.
  $echo htmlentities($body);  //sanitize your output or suffer XSS-attacks
  .....
}
```

If you want to use the output of one SELECT as the input of another select **do not use a loop** but use a join instead:

```
SELECT e.body, e.subject, e.header, e.whatever FROM emails e
INNER JOIN newsletter n ON (n.id = e.newsletter_id)
WHERE n.id = 1466
```

Comment: Only the email address is being stored into the database. My system is very basic. Everything else is predefined and set outside of that very small snippet I added above. Being that the email is the only thing I need i think Tim G is on the right track. Though my host just went down so i cant test anything about.